# Inserting Versioned Features Limit

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, editing, feature-class, versioning

How many features can a user create in a single edit session (insert into versioned table)? is there a limit ?

I tried inserting 6000 features, but I started getting an error at around 3500 and the editor refused to save my edits giving the message:

> FDO error: -2147216072

Is it possible that there is a limit on how many features one can insert per session ?

Comment: What sort of features are you adding? are they complex features? Polygons with lots of nodes?, I have pulled 4 million addresses into a SDE Database without problems so 6000 should be possible.  I noticed on the ESRI Geonet website, it does link that error with running out of disk space

Comment: No polygons, just lines and points. I am gonna take a look at that disk space issue, although I have plenty of space

Answer (score 1):

I would guess the problem is in quality of the data rather than the quantity.

Try beginning your insert at the 3000th feature and see if the second half of the features are inserted.

Comment: it has nothing to do with the quality, I restarted arcmap, and started off from the record that it stopped at in the earlier session, and loaded the rest. So I crossed out quality.

Comment: @ZZZ just to be sure, you might restart a few records just before the error occured

Comment: @zzz I found another post where a user mentioned that this error is related to drive space.  https://geonet.esri.com/thread/113423 so perhaps inserting features requires some extra space.  TRy your insert again after increasing your available drivespace.